# Create line break in WhatsApp message

Tags: php, jquery, html, whatsapp

I have been working on WhatsApp sharing message using:

**whatsapp-button.js**

```
$_u.="Product Name:".$_productName."\n";

$_u.="Sku:".$_productSku."\n";

<a href="whatsapp://send" data-text="<?php echo nl2br($_u); ?>" data-href="" class="wa_btn <?php echo $buttonsize; ?>" style="display:none">Share</a>
```

How to add a line break:

I have tried `\n`, `\r\n`, `PHP_EOL`, and `%0D%0A`, but it just displays as text.

Comment: replace \n with \r\n ;)

Comment: Try to use: `PHP_EOL` instead of `\n`. does that do the trick for you?

Comment: And you sure you didn't messed something up in your a tag? `"<?php echo nl2br($_u); ?> Url:"`

Comment: try `%0D` (carriage return)

Comment: Also don't use nl2br() if you try with PHP_EOL!

Comment: not working this also.

Comment: @ravipatel have you found solution ?

Comment: Not gating solution until now....developer say at that time not possible

Comment: @ravipatel any solution found?

Answer (score 81):

If you want to send an only text containing newline

```
use this %0a


link =`whatsapp://send?text=%0a‎Hello%0aWorld`;
```

If you want to send some url link with text containing newline

```
var encodedURL = encodeURIComponent(some_url);
link =`whatsapp://send?text=${encodedURL}%0a‎Hello%0aWorld`;
```

Now embedded this link in anchor tag

```
<a href=link> Click here! </a>
```

Comment: In RTL languages it stopped working , the  %0a gets printed in the message and does not add a new line (Using selenium not the URL).

Answer (score 31):

To create a line break in WhatsApp you can use this command. It's working fine and I am using it:

```
use `%0a`
```

For example:

```
smsContain = "*Greetings from  " + cname + " ,%0a %0aM/s. " + txtName.Text + " %0a %0aYour Bill for Advertisement is generated ; %0a %0aBill Date  :-  " + DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimePicker1.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " %0a %0aBill no  :-  " + lblBillNo.Text + "  %0a %0aBilling Amount of Rs.  " + lblNet_Amt.Text + " %0a %0aAdvertisement Published in  " + news + " in " + Edi + "  edition,%0a %0aReleased Date : " + DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Parse(dt).ToShortDateString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + ".%0a %0aPlease find the Bill attached below, and request you to please  release the payment ASAP. %0a %0a %0aAny descripancy in regards to this Bill to reported to us immediately.%0a %0a %0aAlways at your Service....* ";
                smsContain = smsContain.Replace("&", "+%26+");
```

Comment: perfect answer.

Answer (score 21):

https://wa.me/+99123456789?text=Line%0aBreak

The `%0a` represents the line break

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

I got one working solution:

HTML:

```
$_u.="Product Name:".$_productName."\n";
$_u.="Sku:".$_productSku."\n";

<a data-text="<?php echo $_u; ?>" data-link="" class="whatsapp">Share</a>
```

JS:

```
           var isMobile = {
                Android: function() {
                    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
                },
                BlackBerry: function() {
                    return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
                },
                iOS: function() {
                    return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
                },
                Opera: function() {
                    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
                },
                Windows: function() {
                    return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
                },
                any: function() {
                    return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
                }
                };
                $(document).on("click", '.whatsapp', function() {
                    if( isMobile.any() ) {

                        var text = $(this).attr("data-text");
                        var url = $(this).attr("data-link");
                        var message = encodeURIComponent(text) + " - " + encodeURIComponent(url);
                        var whatsapp_url = "whatsapp://send?text=" + message;
                        window.location.href = whatsapp_url;
                    } else {
                        alert("Please share this in mobile device");
                    }

                });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution in [here](https://github.com/kriskbx/whatsapp-sharing/issues/16#issuecomment-294854157) which basically is using:

```
whatsappMessage = window.encodeURIComponent(whatsappMessage)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `&#13;`. It is a special HTML code.

For example:

> Hello!`&#13;`How are you today?

will get a result like this:

> Hello! 
> How are you today?