# How to break line in What'sApp web version in 2022?

Tags: php, whatsapp

I am trying to use my code where i will be fetching the data dynamically

```
<a href="https://wa.me/6{{ telephone }}" target="_blank">{{ telephone }}</a>
```

And when the code translate its run as

`https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=601121789198&text&app_absent=0`

[image]

I need to break the line and i have tried

\n, \r\n, PHP_EOL, and %0D%0A,

but it just displays as text.

Can you guys suggest me a solution?

**Any help will be highly appreciated**

Comment: It used to work with a properly URL-encoded newline, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27780542/create-line-break-in-whatsapp-message If it has stopped working now, then I would guess Facebook has probably removed it, and it is not possible any more.

Comment: Yeah did tried these solution before and non of them worked :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone who is checking/following this thread I was able to resolve this issue.

Yes its true that web What's App version doesn't show the line break in text in browser any more [image: pic of api url in browser]

You may want to use this tool
[URL Encode and Decode Tool](https://www.url-encode-decode.com/)

and add the encoded text into your code and click continue to chat you will see the line breaks as you set them.